# How long can the files in a PWA app be cached and max size of the files that can be cached?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, progressive-web-apps

How long can the files in a PWA app be cached?
Can the files cached in PWA app be permanent?
What is the maximum size of the file that can be cached?
Can this cached files be cleared/removed accidentally especially when user clears the web browser cache?